# csh script variable substitution

Tags: csh

I have a small script that performs the following actions.  I have simplified it for this example.

```
set logfile=$HOME/LOG/output.log
find execute.sh -type f -exec csh -c '"$1" >& "$logfile" &' {} \;
```

The issue is that the find command is not expanding the `$logfile` value.  Instead it is giving me an error

```
logfile: Undefined variable.
```

I am not that familiar with csh, nor have I done scripting for quite a while, but is it possible to escape this or otherwise gain access to the value in the command?

Comment: Don't use `csh`; read [Csh programming considered harmful](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html). Try `zsh`, `fish` or `bash`

Comment: Thanks.  I've read it and made my case in the past but don't have a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logfile` is not an environment variable, so it doesn't exist in the shell started by the `-exec` primary. You can either use `setenv`:

```
setenv logfile "$HOME/LOG/output.log"
```

or change the quotes so that `$logfile` is expanded before passing the command to `csh`. It's not clear to me how `$1` is supposed to be set, though.

Answer (score 0):

[ I recognize how old this question is, but it still shows up early in searches ]
In plain C-shell (/bin/csh, and emulators which restrict syntax to match), the variable setting must be delimited with spaces, thus

```
set logfile = $HOME/LOG/output.log
```

In Tcsh, the spaces are optional.  If your script was written for strict C-shell compatibility, your first line ended up setting a rather peculiar variable to an empty string: on my Mac, it would have been `logfile=/Users/kelsey/LOG/output.log` = "".